# Beyond Compare Default encoding Issues

Tags: notepad++, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I am having a hard time on generating the desired output. First Ive set the default encoding by going to Session>Session Settings>Format>Encoding Overrides then setting it as UTF-8. When I drag the file, it automatically reads the file as the default encoding of the file(Central European). How will the beyond compare Encoding work if this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use UTF-8 for all comparisons you need to change the File Format directly, rather than the session settings.  Go to `Tools->File Formats...`, select the file type, and change the `Encoding` combobox on the `Conversion` tab.